# Create object from Class<?>

Tags: java

Ultimately, I need to be able to do this in my code:

```
User result = goo.getEntity("users", "id1").getAs(User.class);
```

However, in the above code I need to explicitly cast the result of `getEntity` to `User`, what is the approach so that the return type of `getAs` will be whatever .class is put into the method.

Here is the underlying psuedo-code:

```
public class EntityType {
    Map json = null;
    public EntityType(Map json){
        this.json = json;
    }
    public Class<?> getAs(Class<?> clazz){
        // create clazz object from json map 
    }
}

public EntityType getEntity(String kind, String id){
    Map json = getFromServer(kind, id);
    EntityType entity = new EntityType(json);
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class EntityType {
    Map json = null;
    public EntityType(Map json){
        this.json = json;
    }
    public <T extends EntityType> T getAs(Class<T> clazz){
        if(clazz.isInstance(this)) {
          return (T) this;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: the Class<T> that is passed in the getAs method does not really extends from EntityType

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
public <T> T getAs(Class<T> clazz) {
```

Note: You are assigning the return as `User result =`, the return type should be `T` instead of `Class<T>`.

Comment: That is, there is no compiler errors. however when I run I get InstantiationException

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?